# How many lines is best to batch before sending the ILP data to QuestDB?

Tags: questdb

I read somewhere that Influx supports only 1000 metrics (lines of data) one can send via ILP. What is the maximum for QuestDB?

I am batching 1000 lines currently before calling socket.send(), will the speed go up if I send more in one go?

Answer (score 1):

When you call send() on the socket it does not create any application level batching, just starts sending the byte buffer over the network. QuestDB batches all incoming data using parameters

- `commitLag`
- `maxUncommittedRows`

described at

https://questdb.io/docs/guides/out-of-order-commit-lag/